# How can I call a function using a column value in each row as a parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the following select statement in a stored procedure to get data from a table, with a function that returns a JSON for one of the columns. What am I doing wrong in my query?

The function `GetRecordComments` requires two parameters, with the first one being the `RecordID` of each row. When I use this query though, I get the following error. How can I call the function passing the recordID as parameter for each row?

Query:

```
SELECT 
    RercordID, Name, Region, 
    dbo.GetRecordComments((SELECT RecordID 
                           FROM RecordList  
                           WHERE RecordID = a.RecordID), 1),
    [Address],
    dbo.GetRecordComments((SELECT RecordID 
                           FROM RecordList  
                           WHERE RecordID = a.RecordID), 2)
FROM 
    RecordList AS a
```

Error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Why not `.., Region, dbo.GetRecordComments(RecordID, 1), [Address], ..`?

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it is very strange that `RecordId` would be repeated in a table called `RecordList`.  But clearly it is.  Happily the subqueries are not necessary:

```
SELECT rl.RecordID, rl.Name, rl.Region, 
       dbo.GetRecordComments(rl.RecordID, 1),
       rl.Address,
       dbo.GetRecordComments(rl.RecordID, 2)
FROM RecordList rl;
```

You should know that such user-defined functions are generally performance killers.  My guess is that you have a comments table.  An explicit `JOIN` is usually much preferable.